# How can I fix this XML schema

Tags: xml

I keep getting the error:

> 's4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'trail' is invalid. Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.'

in my IDE for my XML schema. I'm not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Schema

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="tm"
           xmlns:tm="tm" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="lat" type="xs:decimal" />
<xs:element name="long" type="xs:decimal" />
<xs:element name="difficulty" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="url" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="rating" type="xs:decimal" />
<xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="directions" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="length" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="features" type="xs:string" />

    <xs:complexType name="trail">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:element ref="id" />
            <xs:element ref="name" />
            <xs:element ref="lat" />
            <xs:element ref="long" />
            <xs:element ref="difficulty" />
            <xs:element ref="url" />
            <xs:element ref="rating" />
            <xs:element ref="description" />
            <xs:element ref="directions" />
            <xs:element ref="length" />
            <xs:element ref="features" />
        </xs:complexContent>    
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="trailMaps">
            <xs:element type="trail" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<trailmaps xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="trailmaps.xsd">

    <trail>
        <id>286997</id>
        <name>USA</name>
        <url>https://www.singletracks.com/bike-trails/usa/</url>
        <length>12.0</length>
        <description>Singletrack, roots, some sand, most hard pack, mostly flat, bridges over water.</description>
        <directions>Behind University of Southern Alabama</directions>
        <lat>30.69839</lat>
        <long>-88.17975</long>
        <difficulty>Beginner</difficulty>
        <features></features>
        <rating>4</rating>
    </trail>
</trailmaps>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: Element 'element' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945363/s4s-elt-invalid-content-1-element-element-is-invalid-misplaced-or-occurs-to)

Answer (score 0):

Your schema has many problems. Did you mean something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tm="tm" targetNamespace="tm" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="trailMaps" type="tm:trailMapsType" />
    <xs:complexType name="trailType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lat" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="long" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="difficulty" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="url" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="rating" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="directions" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="length" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="features" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="trailMapsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="trailMap" type="tm:trailType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And then your xml would look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n1:trailMaps xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="tm Untitled1.xsd" xmlns:tm="http://www.example.com/" xmlns:n1="tm">
    <n1:trailMap>
        <n1:id>286997</n1:id>
        <n1:name>USA</n1:name>
        <n1:lat>30.69839</n1:lat>
        <n1:long>-88.17975</n1:long>
        <n1:difficulty>Beginner</n1:difficulty>
        <n1:url>https://www.singletracks.com/bike-trails/usa/</n1:url>
        <n1:rating>4</n1:rating>
        <n1:description>Singletrack, roots, some sand, most hard pack, mostly flat, bridges over water.</n1:description>
        <n1:directions>Behind University of Southern Alabama</n1:directions>
        <n1:length>12.0</n1:length>
        <n1:features/>
    </n1:trailMap>
</n1:trailMaps>
```

Though it'd be much simpler if the schema was like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tm="tm" targetNamespace="tm" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="trailMaps" type="tm:trailMapsType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="trailType">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="lat" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:attribute name="long" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:attribute name="difficulty" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="url" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="rating" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="directions" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="features" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="trailMapsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="trailMap" type="tm:trailType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And then the xml would look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n1:trailMaps xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="tm Untitled1.xsd" xmlns:tm="http://www.example.com/" xmlns:n1="tm">
    <n1:trailMap id="286997" name="USA" lat="30.69839" long="-88.17975" difficulty="Beginner" url="https://www.singletracks.com/bike-trails/usa/" rating="4" description="Singletrack, roots, some sand, most hard pack, mostly flat, bridges over water." directions="Behind University of Southern Alabama" length="12.0" features=""/>
</n1:trailMaps>
```